# How to get ID of last inserted row using denodb?

Tags: typescript, deno, denodb

I am dealing with the work of `DenoDb` and trying to make the `createCat` function return the type `Promise<CatModel>`.
What is the best way to do it?
Here is my current code:

```
import { Model, Database, SQLite3Connector, DataTypes } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts';

interface CatModel {
    id: bigint;
    name: string;
}

const connector = new SQLite3Connector({
  filepath: './db.sqlite',
});
const db = new Database(connector);

class CatSchema extends Model {
  static table = 'cats';
  static fields = {
      id: {
          type: DataTypes.BIG_INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
      },
      name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
      }
  };
}

db.link([CatSchema]);
await db.sync({ drop: true });

const createCat = async (name: string): Promise<CatSchema> => {
    return await CatSchema.create({
        name: name
    });
};

const dataCat = await createCat("Three");
console.log(dataCat);

await db.close();

Deno.exit(1);
```

I'm trying to make a function like this:

```
const createCat = async (name: string): Promise<CatModel>
```

How to convert `Promise<CatSchema>` to `Promise<CatModel>` correctly?
I plan to hide the work with `DenoDB` in the `CatsRepo` class in the future and give only `CatModel`. Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Model.create`](https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/blob/v1.0.40/lib/model.ts#L444) returns an object which includes the id of the last inserted row as a `number`, and that property is called `lastInsertId`. Because `denodb` returns a `number` type, there's not much value in using `bigint` for the id of your `CatModel`, so you can just change it to `number`, then modify your function like this:

`so-70550010.ts`:

```ts
import {
  Database,
  DataTypes,
  Model,
  SQLite3Connector,
} from "https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.40/mod.ts";

class CatSchema extends Model {
  static table = "cats";
  static fields = {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIG_INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  };
}

interface CatModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

async function createCat(name: string): Promise<CatModel> {
  const model = await CatSchema.create({ name });
  const id = model.lastInsertId as number;
  return { id, name };
}

async function main() {
  const connector = new SQLite3Connector({ filepath: ":memory:" });
  const db = new Database(connector);
  db.link([CatSchema]);
  await db.sync({ drop: true });

  for (const name of ["One", "Two", "Three"]) {
    const catModel = await createCat(name);
    console.log(catModel);
  }

  await db.close();
  await connector.close();
  Deno.exit();
}

if (import.meta.main) main();
```

```
$ deno run so-70550010.ts
{ id: 1, name: "One" }
{ id: 2, name: "Two" }
{ id: 3, name: "Three" }
```

> If you want lower-level control while working with SQLite, I recommend https://deno.land/x/sqlite instead of `denodb`.

Comment: Do you think it will be better through find?
```const createCat = async (name: string): Promise<CatModel|null> => {
    const result = await CatSchema.create({ name: name });
    const id = result.lastInsertId as number;
    const data: CatSchema = await CatSchema.find(id);
    console.log(data);
    if (data.name !== name) {
        return null;
    }
    const model: CatModel = {
        id: data.id as number,
        name: data.name as string
    };
    return model;
};```

Comment: No, there’s no need to query for data that you already have in scope.